# Why is my TextView displaying at top of the screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView in android `RelativeLayout` .But the problem that i am facing is that this textView is getting displayed at the top of the screen while i want it in bottom of the screen .Here is my codes..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pnr_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="6"
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
android:layout_row="6"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to put TextView at the top of the screen in android?

Comment: be sure first... Top or Bottom?

Comment: At the start you asked that you want `TextView` on bottom and in the end you are demanding at the bottom of screen. Be specific what you want exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of layout-gravity use gravity field.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="6"
android:layout_row="6"
android:gravity="right|bottom"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want it at top put,

```
android:gravity="right|top"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="bottom|right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0f0f0f"
            android:text="TextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Relativelayout use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

It will make the view in bottom and right.